# Tracking Submit form button click with Google Tag Manager

Tags: events, listener, tracking

I am trying to track a specific submit button click on a form I have on my website using tag manager. I have already:

1. Set up a form submit listener tag with a rule set to fire on every page.
2. Set up an analytics event tag, with a rule set to fire when the event equals gtm.formSubmit, AND when the element ID equals submit1 (the ID of the submit button).

However, it doesn't seem to be showing any events tracked in Analytics when I test this out.

Have I implemented this incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested first in Debug mode of Tag Manager? That is the best way to confirm first that the tag fires. Once that works, only then look in Analytics, in Real Time area. If you see it firing in Debug mode but not in Analytics then some filter might be at fault. Once it starts working Publish it in GTM.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important things to notice and remember:-

1) The element ID is the ID of the form and not the submit button.

2) You should also create a new Tag with "Tag Type = Form Submit Listener"

This article should be helpful: http://www.bwired.com.au/blogs/services-domain/getting-started-with-google-tag-manager